# Ruby testing expect a command to be ran

Tags: ruby, command, minitest, stubbing

I testing my Rails application with Minitest and [Mocha](http://gofreerange.com/mocha/docs/) for unit- and integration tests and want to test whether a commandline command gets called with certain parameters.

Say, I have a class:

```
class Provisioning::Backup
  def create(path)
    system("tar -czf #{path} bar.tar.gz")
  end
end
```

My test *only* wants to know if that command with these parameters gets run. And not whether it uses `system()` or its alternative ``` `` ```. Or even through resque and so on. I want to test the outsides, not the internal implementation.

Hence I am not happy with my current solution in *test/integration/user_requests_backup_test.rb*:

```
class UserRequestsBackupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "requests for a backup runs a backup-script" do
    contact = contacts(:harry)
    site = contact.sites.first

    Provisioning::Backup.expects(:system).with("tar -xzf foo bar")

    post "/v1/sites/#{site.id}/backups"
    assert_response :success
  end

  # backup is already pending
  # backup fails
end
```

This works, but asserts implementation rather then behaviour because `Provisioning::Backup.expects(:system).with("tar -xzf foo bar")` assumes too much about the inner workings and will fail as soon as I move this to e.g. resque.

What are my other options? Is there a way to mock or stub and expect `system` on a lower level? Is there maybe a pattern or gem that allows mocking out and expecting commands in a more generic way?

Answer (score 1):

there is a rule of thumb that you should "only mock the objects you own". In this case, it looks like you want to ensure that a compressed archive was created. You should probably have an object or method somewhere in your application who's sole responsibility is to perform this action.

Let's assume you have a method named `create_archive` that does this. With proper unit test coverage on `create_archive` you can simply verify that it was called from within your integration test.
You should expect and verify that this method gets called, not the call to [`Kernel#system`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system) or [`` Kernel#` ``](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-60). Those calls are implementation details, and you want to verify the logic (`create_archive`) instead.

```
class UserRequestsBackupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "requests for a backup runs a backup-script" do
    contact = contacts(:harry)
    site = contact.sites.first

    Provisioning::Backup.expects(:create_archive)

    post "/v1/sites/#{site.id}/backups"
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is integration test. You also need a low level unit test which doesn't care the result of `system` method but make sure it will be called correctly.

I only know the Rspec way to do this but not minitest, which utilize rspec-mock module.

```
describe Provisioning::Backup do
  subject { Provisioning::Backup.new }

  it "calls system method correctly" do
    subject.should_receive(:system).with('tar -czf #{path} bar.tar.gz')
    subject.create
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, I also have unit-tests which test the methods and so on. My question is that I want my Integration-test to test less implementation, *because* I am testing that implementation in the unit-tests. My question is about how to /not/ test implementation in my integration-test.